# Friedlander Conjecture

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, kt.k-theory-and-homology

I just read on the ALGTOP discussion list that Morel has announced a proof of the Friedlander conjecture. Question: Are there other applications besides the Milnor conjecture $H_*(G,F_p)=H_*(BG,F_p)$ for complex algebraic groups $G$? And, for an outsider to algebraic geometry, what is the motivation to consider etale cohomology and how does it relate to ordinary cohomology, i.e. how does Friedlander imply Milnor?

Comment: Morel explains it nicely in the video (I don't have time to type up the explanation on my phone)

Answer (score 5):

As indicated by D. Roberts, see the [video of Morel's talk](http://www.ima.umn.edu/2011-2012/SW1.30-2.1.12/abstracts.html#11894) at the Abel Conference in honour of Milnor held very recently!

Also, see [Friedlander's own historical survey](http://www.math.northwestern.edu/~eric/preprints/fm-conj/mislin-galley.pdf)!